Sustainsys.Saml2 and MS Entra MetaData Loading Issues
I've got a legacy app using .NET Framework 4.7.2 Web App (non-mvc) for which we need to incorporate SSO with MS Entra. We decided to use Sustainsys.Saml2 HttpModule library v2.9.2 since it seems to be widely used and I've used it in the past on other projects.
We've setup our web.config file as follows, where my-tenant-id and my-tenant-name are the Id and Name from Ms Entra, respectively.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://localhost:50001/" 
                  modulePath="/Saml2"  
                  authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Always" 
                  minIncomingSigningAlgorithm="SHA256">
  <nameIdPolicy allowCreate="true" format="Persistent" />
  <requestedAuthnContext classRef="Unspecified" comparison="Exact" />
  <metadata cacheDuration="PT42S" validDuration="7.12:00:00" wantAssertionsSigned="true">
    <requestedAttributes>
      <add name="Minimal" />
    </requestedAttributes>
  </metadata>
  <identityProviders>
    <add entityId="https://{my-tenant-id}.ciamlogin.com/{my-tenant-id}/" 
         signOnUrl="https://{my-tenant-name}.ciamlogin.com/{my-tenant-id}/saml2" 
         logoutUrl="https://{my-tenant-name}.ciamlogin.com/{my-tenant-id}/saml2" 
         allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" 
         binding="HttpRedirect">
      <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/SAML2/MsEntra/Test1.cer" />
    </add>
  </identityProviders>
  <federations>
    <add metadataLocation="~/App_Data/SAML2/MsEntra/Test1.xml" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" />
  </federations>
  <serviceCertificates>
    <add use="Both" 
         status="Current" 
         metadataPublishOverride="None" 
         fileName="~/App_Data/SAML2/Sustainsys/Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx" />
  </serviceCertificates>
</sustainsys.saml2>

Everything seems to work just fine, but I'm getting an error from the library writing to our logs.

2024-08-27 17:42:39.2319|INFO|Saml2|Loading metadata for federation from ~/App_Data/SAML2/MsEntra/Test1.xml

The XML file is what we downloaded from the MS Entra app without manipulation. I did notice, however, the xml has this:
<EntityDescriptor ID="_7...e" entityID="https://sts.windows.net/{my-tenant-id}/" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">

As you can see the EntityId does not match that which was given to us by MS Entra. I tried using the EntityId from the xml in my web.config file https://sts.windows.net/{ms-entra-id}/, but then I get an application error and the app does not work:

The given key was not present in the dictionary.

It might not be a big deal since everything "works", but, how can this be resolved so our log files are filled with this error. I'd prefer to solve the error, rather than prevent the error from being logged.
